# Java. Ошибка при переводе массива в строку

Tags: java

При переводе массива в строку

```
            String str3="20150";
            byte[] b3=str3.getBytes();
            System.out.println(b3);
    //Массив байтов переводим обратно в строку 
            try{
            String s=new String(b3,"[B@15db9742");
            System.out.println(s);
            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
```

выдаётся сообщение

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       UnsupportedEncodingException cannot be resolved to a type

Как устранить эту проблему?

Comment: `[B@15db9742` странный аргумент. Попробуйте `Charset.defaultCharset()` вместо

Comment: конкретно ошибка компиляции лечится импортом класса `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException`. Но вы странное что-то делаете, начиная от вывода массива (`toString()` у массивов выводит такую ерунду (тип@хэшкод_экземпляра), как у вас, поэтому стоит вызывать `Arrays.toString(b3)`, чтобы получить человекочитаемую строку). Также, `getBytes()` служит для получения байтового представления строки с использованием указанной кодировки (или кодировки по-умолчанию, как у вас). В общем, будет лучше, если вы расскажете, зачем вы это все написали.

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @zRrr_"В общем, будет лучше, если вы расскажете, зачем вы это все написали."_Это код с сайта  study-java.ru (Урок 7).

Answer (score 2):

Сам код

```
    try{
    String s=new String(b3,"UTF-8");
    System.out.println(s);
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

}
```

если помог, то очень рад

Comment: _В общем, будет лучше, если вы расскажете, зачем вы это все написали._Это код с study-java.ru (Урок 7).

Comment: в смысле зачем? я не проверял человека на плагиат. У него появилась ошибка, я ее исправил.Мне нет разницы откуда человек берет этот код.